# Можно ли писать несколько сравнений в условии

Tags: javascript

Допустимо ли написать такое выражение : если число больше или равно 18 и  меньше или равно 65, то вывести текст

```
var i
If (i > 18 =< 65) {
alert('какой-то текст')
}
```

Comment: Написать - допустимо. Но надеяться, что оно выполнит то, что ты хочешь - глупо.

Comment: @Akina, почему глупо?

Comment: @Air Достаточно прочитать две страницы мануала - описание использованных операторов и описание их приоритета. И на основе этой информации понять, что же будет выполнено на самом деле, и что будет означать результат.

Comment: @Akina, я понял о чем ты... Я даже обратил внимание, что условие  описано неграмотно...)))) Обычная невнимательность...

Comment: чет стыдно) я ведь знал как писать, только забыл :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var i = 18;
if(i >= 18 && i <= 65)
 console.log('какой-то текст');
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно делать так:

```
var i;
if (i > 18 && i =< 65) {
  alert('какой-то текст');
}
```